# Quitar la marca blanca al inicio de las líneas modificadas en Intellij-idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Cuando trabajas en Intellij Idea en un proyecto que está vinculado a un repositorio en Github, aparece al comienzo de cada línea modificada una marca blanca.
Cuando estoy en zen-mode esta marca blanca forma una columna blanca que me resulta impertinente.
¿Alguna idea de como quitarla?

[image: una "preciosa" columna blanca]

Answer (score 1):

Cada lenguaje tiene su propia configuración de esquema de colores.

Para ello ve a la ventana de configuracion, si estas en windows llegas rapido con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Despues ve a `Editor > Color Scheme > tu_lenguaje`

Donde `tu_lenguaje` es el nombre del lenguaje en que este tu codigo.
Por ejemplo en mi caso digamos que es COBOL y le colorque me gustaria cambiar es el de las cadenas, en la lista selecciono para el esquema de colores actual el tipo de elemento que deseo personalizar y en el panel de la derecha me salen las opciones de personalización.
Lo primero seria desmarcar la casilla que dice `Inherit values from` en caso de que la tenga, esto significa que cambia el color de acuerdo al tema que selecciones, pero que deseas personalizarlo sin importar el tema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es lo que estoy buscando.